# HTML Base URL and links

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, url

I have the following problem:

The URL is **http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/** and the base is:

```
<base href="http://www.myhomeurl.com/"/>
```

All resources like images, css and javascript will be at:

```
http://www.myhomeurl.com/css/myfile.css
http://www.myhomeurl.com/js/myscript.js
http://www.myhomeurl.com/images/img.jpg
```

BUT, the link will be at "application1", for example:

```
http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/page1.html
http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/page2.html
http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/page3.html
```

The question is: How to apply base URL for resources (like css, js, etc) and apply the base/application1 for page links?

Here is a problem when I have:

```
<a href="page1.html">Click me!</a>
```

When the user clicks this the page will going to:

**http://www.myhomeurl.com/page1.html**

and not to:

**http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/page1.html**

Comment: your application files should start from root and it should exanpand//

Comment: Are you asking for the site to be created or an existing links in existing site? I am asking because it should be known

Answer (score 6):

You could use a base tag and change it so all urls can be relative to the applications base.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Additional information can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

**edit:** w3c spec on base tag http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4 also illustrates how to pull images from other locations.

Comment: I have the base tag... but the resources ... aren't in application1/

Answer (score 4):

Change like this on your resources

```
<link href="./css/myfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Not like

```
<link href="http://www.myhomeurl.com/css/myfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And your base it looks like this

```
<base href="http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this varriable in link  HTTP_SERVER

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/');

<a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER?>myurlpage/page1.html">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late for this question, but I can see none of the answers really do what (I think) you need.

I suggest you to use (as others have already said) a Base Url like this:

```
<base href="http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1/" />
```

This way your links will work in the intended way. Then, when you add resources, you only have to go up to the parent directory, like the following:

```
<link href="../css/myfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url(../css/myfile.css);
</style>
```

Note the `../`, telling the browser to exit from "application1" directory, going up one step in the file structure.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you should have something like this

```
root 

   root/css
   root/js

   root/files/html1.htm
   root/files/htmml2.htm
```

root will be nothing but /// your website name

```
http://www.myhomeurl.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Define two constant one for your css, js resources and one for links and use them across the application:-

```
define('RESOURCE_URL','http://www.myhomeurl.com/');
define('LINK_URL','http://www.myhomeurl.com/application1');
```

so that if any change in base url you can look up to these constants only.

Answer (score 0):

I would start all link herd with /and the top directory of the URI.  That makes them relative to the domain.  Then just put the protocol and domain in the base.

Answer (score 0):

when using base url you should not put `www.` in it.

Next if your url is `mysite.com` and your app is located at `mysite.com/app` then you set your base to be `mysite.com/app` when you use your example `info.html` it will look like `mysite.com/app/info.html`.

You can also use `../app/info.html` and it will look like `mysite.com/app/info.html`